# How to use async/await with mongoose aggregate

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am using async/await in my node applications when I use find() commands but is it possible to do the same with aggregations?

Something like

```
const data = await Model.aggregate([
      {
         $match: {
            "id": id
         }
      }
])
```

Comment: Didn't you try? Yes, you can do it for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can do it like 
for example

```
router.get('/something',async function(req, res, next) {
const data = await Model.aggregate([
      {
         $match: {
            "id": id
         }
      }
])
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead

```
const agg = Model.aggregate([
      {
         $match: {
            "id": id
         }
      }
])

const data = await agg.exec()
```

This worked for me, Omega Cube's answer didn't :/

Answer (score 1):

as for mongodb 4.4, aggregation is added with exec.

```
async function _(){
   const data = await Model.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         "id": id
      }
     }
   ]).exec();
   return data
}
```